# SSIS 2005 Conditional Split Expression Syntax to Exclude Data Based on Multiple Departments

Tags: ssis

Good Afternoon All,

I have written an SSIS 2005 package that contains a conditional split.  The expression evaluates a variable, strDepts, as Department (fieldname) != User::strDepts.  The variable strDepts contains 6 department numbers separated by commas.  When I run the package, the conditional split does not work correctly.  No records are being selected.

Do I need to create a variable for each of the 6 departments I want to exclude?  If so, my conditional split expressions would be Department (fieldname) != User::strDept1, Department (fieldsname) != User::strDept2 etc.

Or, is there another way to accomplish this?  The excluded departments don't change frequently.  Thus, I'm not locked in to using variables for this.  Is there a better transformation to use?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only ever going to be 6 departments and you will split depending on which department number the (fieldname) is I would just do 6 evaluations in the split.